# The Frattini subgroup of $D_{\infty}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Please hint me. $\phi(D_{\infty})?$ $\phi(G)$ is Frattini subgroup of $G$, intersection of all the maximal subgroup of $G$ and 
$D_{\infty}=<x,y|x^2=y^2=1>$.

Comment: I'm not sure your questions are the appropriate level for Mathoverflow. Have you tried math.stackexchange instead? MO is for research-level questions, m.SE welcomes questions at any level.

Answer (score 4):

Put $a := xy$ and $b := y$. Then we have ${\rm D}_\infty = \langle a, b \rangle$. Clearly $a$ generates a subgroup of index 2, which is thus maximal. Also, given a prime $p$, the subgroup $G_p := \langle a^p, b \rangle$ has index $p$ in ${\rm D}_\infty$, and is thus maximal as well. The intersection of the groups $G_p$ is $\langle b \rangle$, which intersects trivially with $\langle a \rangle$. Therefore the Frattini subgroup is trivial.